# Detects chained SQL injection attempts 1/2" in PHPSESSID cookie

Tags: php, owasp, mod-security, false-positive

We have ModSecurity installed on our application server and sometimes an request is blocked because ModSecurity detects SQL Injection on PHPSESSID cookie.

> GET /somepage.php HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.domain.com
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101         Firefox/26.0
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Cookie: PHPSESSID=peu4e3ftt**241or**q5nbnuc6ocs4
>   Connection: keep-alive
>
> Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). [file "C:/Program
>   Files/Apache Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/extra/modsecurity_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"]
>   [line "539"] [id "981248"] [msg "Detects chained SQL injection
>   attempts 1/2"] [data "**241or**"] [severity "CRITICAL"]
>   [tag "WEB_ATTACK/SQLI"] [tag "WEB_ATTACK/ID"]

What is recommended to avoid this false-positive ?

Comment: Why are there `<strong>` tags in the cookie?

Comment: I just trying format the cookie substring for point the error, but not works.

Comment: Ok I think you are right and it may be the `or` part

Comment: I'd be skeptical of mod security blocking any request containing 'or'.. seems very prone to false-positives.

Comment: That's what I thought until I looked at the alert and saw ` [data "241or"] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this rule. If you use all of modsecurity crs rules, it will be so many fale positive.